# trait cannot be made into an object due to generic type parameters

Tags: generics, rust, traits, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects

Throughout my code I have objects which implement Trait1. I also have a variety of object which implement Trait2, which expects Trait1 objects as a parameter. When I try to create a vector of objects which fulfill Trait2 I get a compiler error.

Simplest reproduction I could get:

```
trait Trait1 {
    fn doit(&self);
}

trait Trait2 {
    fn do_other_thing(&self, obj: &impl Trait1);
}

fn main() {
    let mut myvec = Vec::<Box<dyn Trait2>>::new();
}
```

Which results in the compiler error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Trait2` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:10:18
   |
5  | trait Trait2 {
   |       ------ this trait cannot be made into an object...
6  |     fn do_other_thing(&self, obj: &impl Trait1);
   |        -------------- ...because method `do_other_thing` has generic type parameters
...
10 |     let mut myvec = Vec::<Box<dyn Trait2>>::new();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Trait2` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = help: consider moving `do_other_thing` to another trait
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this? 'myvec' has to be dynamic on Trait2, since I   expect to hold different types which implement this trait. Is there any way to also allow 'obj' to be fully generic on Trait1 or do I have to tie it to one specific type that implements Trait1?

Comment: Can you modify Trait2?

Comment: To apply my answer to the other question here: just change `impl Trait1` to `dyn Trait1`.